# Not able to click a button using nightwatch , since button's bottom edge touches footer and no scroll space

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I am using Nightwatch for automating scripts.
Facing an issue, not able to click a button using Nightwatch, since the button's bottom edge touches footer and no scroll space.

I tried 
1.  `browser.maximizeWindow();`  but command doesn't works.
2. `browser.windowSize('current', 1200, 1200, function(result) {});`  it works but on different machines and env it might cause issue.

Is there any other solution to click on a button which will work independently?

Comment: what is the api you are using to click the button?

Comment: i am using  .click('@id')

Comment: are you getting any error or the click has no impact?

Comment: Use the Js to click on the button, by that way you don't have to worry about the location of the button on the page.